# How to remove the square bracket from the python lists

Tags: django, python-3.x, list, dataframe

While writing an Html file from a text file, square brackets like below are occurring which we want to remove.

```
<tr><td><a href=['http://www.ubuntu.com/']></a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href=['http://wiki.ubuntu.com/']></a></td></tr>
```

Following is the code through which writing an Html file:

```
for lines in contents.readlines():
    if lines.strip():
        e.write("\t"+"<tr><td><a href=%s></a></td></tr>\n"%lines.split())
```

Not getting any idea to remove square brackets from the above code. Can someone help us out, please?

Answer (score 1):

The `split()` is turning your strings to lists. Change your `%lines.split()` to just `%lines`.

Comment: @SyedSulaimanHabeebQuadri Glad to hear that! Please consider accepting the most helpful answer by clicking the checkmark icon. Thanks!

Comment: We improved a bit of it.
`for lines in contents.readlines():`
  `if lines.strip():`
   `line = re.sub(r'^\[|\]$', '', lines)`
   `e.write("\t"+f"<tr><td><a href=\"{line}\">{line}</a></td></tr>\n")`